# Facebook Hash Key does not match even though the correct key is in the stored keys

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, hash, key

My facebook integration is not working when I run the signed apk. It works in the debug build (which has a different Hash Key). I have have double checked the following:

- Facebook App ID used in the application, it is still correct.
- I have printed out the hash key. It matches the key added in the Key Hashes.
- The key mentioned in the error (in LogCat), that was not found, is also the same key that I printed out and that already exists in the stored Key Hashes list.

So, I don't know what changed and why can't the facebook api match these keys. It was working fine before, nothing has been changed in the code. The keys are identical. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it! Somehow the key generated using the code did not work for the release build. Eventually used the keytool to generate the release key and it worked.